# How to get the address of the target method when you are calling a method of a class in ARM instructions

Tags: android, arm

As we know, Android compile the app into ARM instruction to make the app run fast.
When I was analysing the machine instructions of an APP in Android, I found the target address of a class's method is hard to understand.

For example, the target of the method call `telephonymanager.getdeviceid()` is computed as follow:

1. [r1,#16]->r5
2. r5->r1
3. [r1,#0]->r0
4. [r0,#572]->r0
5. [r0,#40]->lr
6. blx lr

Can you please tell me why this piece of code can get the target address, especially what the value 572 and 40 mean?

I have found some explanation for the arm instruction. But most of them only concentrate on the function call, but not method call of a class. Can you please tell me some blog or paper about this thing?

Comment: It is probably difficult to say.  In C++, you have a class/object memory.  The object memory looks like 'step 1/2' and the `vtable` is got in step '3' and the function is looked at in '4/5'.  I don't know why android would have two of these '4/5'.  It is probably up to the Android dispatch methods/class organization; which will depend on Android version?  I think they have change the virtual machine and probably this dispatch.

Comment: Thank you,  that is why i didn't understand how the ARM instruction call a method of a class